# Track why my web page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am working on java struts 1.3 framework. One of my jsp page when loads,after a second it reloads itself.By this time the buttons on page are unresponsive(I can not click on them).Is there any way to find what script is causing this error? I tried removing my window.onload script but the issue still persists.The page contains large bundle of js files included by designers.But how do I track which file or what code is causing this.Please help.

Comment: Comment all js import, now one by one un-comment those import to verify the culprit

Comment: use chrome or firefox. Open your webpage(jsp) on browser and right click to open inspect element/developer tool. there you will see console .It will show you if any javascript has error . Also retry open your page after clearing cache/cookies .

Comment: I do use firebug for finding such errors but even js console not giving error.Thanks anyways

Comment: Seems you are using FF, try Chrome and check whether you are getting same response. If so, keep debug point in last line(not under any functions) of last Javascript import and check what is happening after that.

Comment: I think I got the problem.The page initially did not have any ckeditor in it.Now it contains total 5 ckeditors.The page once loads for rest of the elements and jumps once to show up ck editors